# Analytics for Firebase - User Properties with Google Tag Manager

Tags: firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

Does anyone know if there is a way to set User Properties of Analytics for Firebase with Google Tag Manager? 
I'm not finding deep documentation about converging this two tools.

Comment: Not really clear on what you're trying to achieve here. Are you saying you want to send user properties to Firebase without actually adding the [code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties#set_user_properties) in your app?

Comment: I want to set a User Propertie from GTM, im doing this because im working with an app that is not mine but i have to measure analytic stuff with Firebase. 
I know that i have to add some code in this app but i want to call that code from GTM and setting this user properties here and not doing everything in my code. It's now more clear? Thanks for asking!

Comment: Have you tried a tag calling a function call? In that function (defined in your app) you would set the property based on instructions defined from GTM. I didn't try it but it seems to be a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a user property called exciting_sport and you have written the Firebase code for this user property as follows:

```
Analytics.setUserPropery("exciting_sport", xcitingsport);
```

Now in the GTM console you need to create a new variable that matches the user property key. Take a look at the attached screenshot. [image]

The name of the user property key name should math exactly with the key set in the code. You can use this variable to create a Universal Analytics tag similar and add as a parameter in a event track type. This would work similar to any other event.

You can also add setUserID to the user property and track it likewise.

Comment: What is the GTM user property key for FirebaseAnalytics.setUserId()?

Comment: Did you try this? Does it work? Personally, I get a "Not Defined" when it reaches GA.