# How to setup userID in firebase Analytics using Google Tag Manager

Tags: firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I know it is possible to set the userID in Firebase Analytics with the `FirebaseAnalytics.setUserId(String id)` public method.

But is it possible to do so using an GTM Firebase container by adding the value to an Firebase event?  And if so, how?

Comment: Take a look over here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570633/analytics-for-firebase-user-properties-with-google-tag-manager/46614834#46614834